# Concrete5 8+: Set a custom controller for a block

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

Does anybody know the way how to set custom controller for a block?
Concrete documentation suggests the way of overriding block's controller via application/block/*block_name* folder.
The thing is that approach will override controller for all templates. What if I have a few block templates and don't want to override controller for all templates?
The only way I see - creating a new block type. But I don't think it's a right way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to have a different controller for a block template, you have to create a new block type.